# Get facebook comment by id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have facebook comment box. I want to store the comment in a database when a user comments something. So I am attaching a callback function with `FB.event.subscribe('comment.create', ...` From there I get `commentID` and `href` but the only way to get the exact comment is with FQL which is deprecated from 2011 and nobody knows when facebook will remove it. Using Graph API I can get all comments but there is no way to find out which comment belongs to a specific user of our app (we don't ask for any permissions so there is no access_token; we trigger popup form when somebody comments so it is very important to match user details with comment (that's why we subscribe to `comment.create`)). Is there a smart way to do this or should rely on a deprecated feature?

Edit:

I am trying to get the comment like this:

```
FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: "SELECT text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_fbid = '" + resp.commentID +
                "' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='" + resp.href + "')"
        },
        function (data) {
            var fb_id
                , comment

            console.log(data)

            if ( data.length == 1 ) {
                fb_id = data[0].fromid
                comment = data[0].text
            }

        // ...


    }
)
```

The problem is that when on localhost - it returns array with one element - the comment I want. When I upload to my app - then it returns array with no elements. Maybe there are permission issues. My question is how to get the content of a comment when submitted. What is the canonical way? Is it possible without access_token and permissions?

Comment: Why do you think FQL is deprecated? It's not, and IDs are retrievable via both FQL and the Graph API - your issue isn't really clear, are you trying to retrieve the comments posted for a URL via the comments plugin? `/comments?id=<URL HERE>` should do that in the Graph API

Comment: With `/comments?id=...` I can get all comments. I want to get only the comment with `commentID` from `comment.create` event. I read this article: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/ but maybe I am with the wrong impression?

Comment: Doesn't `/<comment ID>` work directly?

Comment: What do you mean? `http://graph.facebook.com/<comment ID>` doesn't work. It throws `GraphMethodException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FQL isn't deprecated. The blog post is talking about **Rest API** specifically, later on it states changes with FQL.

To access comments you need a valid access token that can view the top level object. Assuming this is just for comments on websites, a normal extended page access token should suffice by following scenario 5 explained at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages.

Then using a page access token from [User ID]/accounts you can pretty much hard code it in (you can create your own backend login tool, in the event that you invalidate the token one day or need to change it) via a server side language for example PHP using the PHP SDK

```
$facebook->setAccessToken('YOUR_PAGE_TOKEN');
```

So from here you can do an AJAX POST to the PHP page where the SDK is loaded

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function(response) {
        onCommentCreate(response.commentID);
    }
);

function onCommentCreate(commentID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'createcomment.php',
        data: {commentid:commentID},
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}

}
```

and request the comment information from there

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset( $_POST['commentid'] ))  {

$commentid = $_POST['commentid'];

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID_HERE',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET_HERE',
));

$facebook->setAccessToken('YOUR_PAGE_TOKEN');

$response = $facebook->api($commentid);

echo $response['from']['id'];

}
?>
```

References

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graphapi/guides/comments/
- https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I almost got it. The only part I still find difficult - which tokens to get and how exactly? I've read that `Comment` object uses generic access token? The problem is that when I get generic access token `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials` and then tried to extend it - it responds with "No user access token specified"

Comment: @cldy page tokens, generic access tokens imply user or page tokens. App access tokens (using this endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secr‌​et=YOUR_APP_SECRET& grant_type=client_credentials`) do not count. You must extend a user token then get a page token as I stated earlier.

Comment: I got confused because I really do not understand why I need page access_tokens? I went to `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer` selected application, checked manage_pages permission; got token; then `/me/accounts`; I see access_tokens for the pages I own. But which one should I select, why do I need this access token? I trigger comments with `.fb-comments` class and `data-href` attribute (from HTML 5 example). Can I ask you for the exact steps which I should take to make your example run? I don't get the access_tokens part (the other part is clear).

Comment: @cldy the comments object needs an access token to request the resource. The only way to get this is either a user or page token. Seeing that you most likely want indefinite access to the comment object, if you use Scenario 5 mentioned earlier, you will be granted a page access token that doesn't expire. The entire createcomment.php is already above and I already listed the html part at http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/experiments/createcomment.html. It doesn't matter if you use HTML5 or FBML, `FB.event.subscribe` is the same function

Comment: Thank you mate, it was a little counterintuitive but finally got it to work. The steps were:
1) Went here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2) Added manage pages and select the app.
3) Followed your instructions - get user token (which is valid for an hour)
4) Got extended access_token
5) Got /me/accounts
6) Selected some page - the access token has no expiration date.